# Ajax doesnt work on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This is clear method of catalog_controller

```
def clear
@page_title = 'Vaciar Carro'
if request.xhr?
  @cart.cart_items.destroy_all
  flash[:cart_notice] = "Carro Vaciado."
  render :controller => 'cart', :action => 'clear_with_ajax'
elsif request.post?
  @cart.cart_items.destroy_all
  flash[:cart_notice] = "Carro Vaciado."
  redirect_to :controller => 'catalog'
else
  render :controller => 'cart', :action => 'clear', :template => 'cart/clear'
end
end
```

this is the clar_with_ajax.js.erb code

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery('#shopping_cart').html("<%= j render :partial =>'cart/cart' %>");
```

and that's the part of the view that calls the clear method

```
<p id='cart_total'><strong>Total: <%= sprintf "%0.2f €", @cart.total %></strong></p>
  <% unless @cart.cart_items.empty? %>
   <p id='clear_cart_link'>
    <b><%= link_to 'Vaciar carro', :controller => 'cart', :action => 'clear' :remote=> true %></b>
</p>
```

Since i have added  remote => true on the view the "Vaciar Carro" link does nothing.

Comment: Did you look to see what is returned from the call?

Comment: What call?i'am totally new in rails

Comment: clear code is in the top of the post

Comment: not the code - what it _actually_ returns when you click the link

Comment: It doesn't makes nothing